# Routing to different container in docker using zuul not working

Tags: api, docker, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I have 2 microservices (spring boot app) running in different docker containers and configured with zuul api gateway. Routing to other container is not working. Container 1 is running in 8030 port & container 2 is running on port 8030.

Below is the zuul configuration in application.yml -

```
server:
  port: 8030

# TODO: figure out why I need this here and in bootstrap.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul server

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

zuul:
  routes:
    zuultest:
         url: http://localhost:8080
         stripPrefix: false 

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

When access through localhost:8030/zuultest/test am getting the exception as -

```
2016-09-19 09:10:14.597  INFO 1 --- [nio-8030-exec-3] hello.SimpleFilter                       : GET request to http://localhost:8030/zuultest/test
2016-09-19 09:10:14.600  WARN 1 --- [nio-8030-exec-3] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
```

Can I know why I am getting this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use links option in the docker-compose.yml to link between the two containers.

```
demo1:
  image: <demo1 image name>
  links: - demo2
demo2:
  image: <demo2 image name>
```

Then in the **zuul:routs:url** configuration you can use the conatiner name, **demo2** instead of it's IP.

Answer (score 0):

How did you start the 2 containers? Both cannot have the same port if you exposed them to the docker host.

```
docker run --name service A --net=host -p 8030:8030 ...
docker run --name service B --net=host -p 8030:8031 ...
```

Without this, if you are calling localhost:8030, you are calling the host (not the container), and you are not getting a response.

You need to map the port to the host when you start them with different ports, and call them with localhost to the right exposed port